# How should we define associations in Sequelize when there is an association for tables across different schemas?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a few tables that have associations across different schemas. When I run model.sync, the table is created with foreign key constraints using the same schema, even though I have defined my models with different schemas.

I am using Sequelize 7, Postgresql and Typescript. Here's an example of what I'm doing:

Book model

```
export class Book extends Model<
  InferAttributes<Book>,
  InferCreationAttributes<Book>
> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare company_id: ForeignKey<Company['id']>;

}

export default (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
  Book.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Book',
      tableName: 'books',
      schema: 'bookstores',
      freezeTableName: true
    }
  );
```

Company model

```
export class Company extends Model<
  InferAttributes<Company>,
  InferCreationAttributes<Company>
> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare name: string;

}

export default (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
  Company.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Company',
      tableName: 'company',
      schema: 'public',
      freezeTableName: true
    }
  );
```

Associations
Company.hasMany(Book, {foreignKey: 'company_id'});
Book.belongsTo(Company, {foreignKey: 'company_id'});

When I run tests, I try to create the tables like this:

```
 for (const model of Object.values(sequelize.models)) {
            await model.sync()
          }
```

I can see in the logs that when the Books table is created, it tries to create a foreign key reference using the schema of Books and not company:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "bookstores"."books" ("id"  SERIAL , "company_id" INTEGER REFERENCES "bookstores"."company" ("id") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));'

This throws an error because the table bookstores.company does not exist.

If I set foreignKeyConstraints to false, it does work but I do want to use FK constraints.
Company.hasMany(Book, {foreignKey: 'company_id', foreignKeyConstraints: false});
Book.belongsTo(Company, {foreignKey: 'company_id', foreignKeyConstraints: false});

Comment: Using Sequelize alpha version might be a bad idea. Looks like a Sequelize issue. Did you search for the similar issues on Sequelize GitHub for v7?

Comment: I found a similar issue for a previous version but nothing specific to v7 https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9270